# How can I mount files in the same sub path in k8s deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have these volume mounts right now defined in my deployment,

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: website-storage
          mountPath: /app/upload
          readOnly: false
          subPath: foo/upload
        - name: website-storage
          mountPath: /app/html
          readOnly: true
          subPath: foo/html/html
```

Now I want to mount another path from my PVC into `/app/html/website-content` and this is what I attempted with,

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: website-storage
          mountPath: /app/upload
          readOnly: false
          subPath: foo/upload
        - name: website-storage
          mountPath: /app/html
          readOnly: true
          subPath: foo/html/html
        - name: website-storage
          mountPath: /app/html/website-content
          readOnly: true
          subPath: foo/website-content
```

This does not work and gives an error during mounting. Is it possible to do this? Do I have to explicitly create the `website-content` folder prior to mounting it? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that during pod initialization there is an attempt to create directory `website-content` in the `/app/html` location which will cause error as the `/app/html` is mounted read only.

You cannot create a folder in the read only system that means you can't mount a volume as the folder doesn't exist, but if there was already the folder created, you can mount the volume.

So all you need is just to create a directory `website-content` in the `foo/html/html` location on the volume before you attach it into container. Then, as it will be mounted to the `/app/html` location, there will be directory `/app/html/website-content`.

For example, you can use a [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) for that. Add this code to your deployment file:

```
initContainers:
  - name: init-container
    image: busybox
    volumeMounts:
    - name: website-storage
      mountPath: /my-storage
      readOnly: false
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /my-storage/foo/html/html/website-content']
```

When the pod is running, you check mount points on the pod using `kubectl describe pod {pod-name}`:

> ```
> Mounts:
> /app/html from website-storage (ro,path="foo/html/html")
> /app/html/website-content from website-storage (ro,path="foo/website-content")
> /app/upload from website-storage (rw,path="foo/upload")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

in my view app/html is already mounted and is read-only, better use different path,

2nd do you need to share volume with more pods ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mount a volume into another volume. Instead you could mount it into a different location and create a symlink to that location during container startup.